# adding a new column and rows to a table access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access like the following:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
|  AGP_ID  | PRAD_ID  | PRAD_TYPE |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| 00803110 | 00803110 | 002       |
| 00803110 | 00803110 | PRI       |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | 002       |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | 003       |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | PRI       |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I want to add a column call Days and in that column for each AGP ID, Then I want to have M, T, W, TH, F, Sat, Sun for each AGP ID. The new table will look like:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
|  AGP_ID  | PRAD_ID  | PRAD_TYPE | Day |
+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
| 00803110 | 00803110 | 002       | M   |
| 00803110 | 00803110 | PRI       | T   |
| 00803110 |          |           | W   |
| 00803110 |          |           | TH  |
| 00803110 |          |           | F   |
| 00803110 |          |           | Sat |
| 00803110 |          |           | Sun |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | 002       | M   |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | 003       | T   |
| 00803153 | 00803153 | PRI       | W   |
| 00803153 |          |           | TH  |
| 00803153 |          |           | F   |
| 00803153 |          |           | Sat |
| 00803153 |          |           | Sun |
+----------+----------+-----------+-----+
```

Any help will be appreciated. I've been pulling my hair over this but it seems so simple compare to the other things I have done.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't waste your time trying my deleted answer. I hadn't understood very well before I answered.

Comment: how big is the table? since there aren't any SQL condition looping through each record might take some time :S :S

Comment: I have a solution but in MySQL, Access don't have stored procedures (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its good idea to loop through each records. you asked for it.. give it a try ;)

throw this code under button click oder a sub.

Open the table in design mode and insert new column Day as text (2 char)
modify the select/update sql command.

```
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database
    Dim myRs As DAO.Recordset

    Set myDB = CurrentDb

    Dim SQL_GET As String
    SQL_GET = "SELECT ID from YOUR_TAbLE"

    Set myRs = myDB.OpenRecordset(SQL_GET)

    Dim mRc As Long
    mRc = Nz(myRs.RecordCount, 0)
    If Not mRc = 0 Then
        Dim dArr(6) As String
        dArr(0) = "MO"
        dArr(1) = "TU"
        dArr(2) = "WE"
        dArr(3) = "TH"
        dArr(4) = "FR"
        dArr(5) = "SA"
        dArr(6) = "SU"

        Dim SQL_SET As String
        Dim I As Integer
        I = 0
        While Not myRs.EOF
            SQL_SET = "UPDATE Your_table SET Day='" & dArr(I) & "' WHERE (ID = " & Nz(myRs("id"), "") & ")"
            On Error GoTo ERROR_SQL1:
            DBEngine.BeginTrans
                myDB.Execute SQL_SET, dbFailOnError
            DBEngine.CommitTrans

            myRs.MoveNext
            If I < 6 Then I = I + 1 Else I = 0
        Wend
    Else
        msgbox "No records found.. :("    
    End If



EXIT_SUB:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myDB = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ERROR_SQL1:
    DBEngine.Rollback
    MsgBox "Error while executing sql_1. " & vbNewLine & "System msg: " & Err.description
    GoTo EXIT_SUB
```

PS: you can remove the beginTrans/commitTrans you don't really need that. i put it for demonstration. also i haven't tested this code but should work..

Comment: This is all very easy if the OP did not want to skip days for existing entries, where is the skip?

Comment: @Fionnuala: OP does not have any SQL condition hence above code. Skip will be implemented in SQL where condition to check whether the record should be updated or not! like: select all records where day is empty and update them?

Comment: Very well, I put that the wrong way round. Where is the insert?

Comment: @Fionnuala: are you serious? :)

Comment: Yes :) Take AGP_ID 00803110, it goes from 2 rows to 7 rows.

Comment: @Fionnuala: that moment when you spot an error in lecturer's code *_*.
Anyway i assumed ID would be there in the table being UNIQUE. that way you are updating only one record not all "AGP_ID 00803110". if no unique fields are present and no way to identify a record uniquely i would suggest to immediately "REDESIGN" the table :)
for the coding sake, you could insert a select command with limit 1 in the update command to force only one record update:D :D:D:D

Comment: I suspect this is some sort of junction table, so the unique identifier is ID + Day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60160/discussion-between-krish-km-and-fionnuala).